# Jenkins builds existing jobs of repo when a new branch is pushed to repo

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a GitHub repository xxx with master, qa, and dev branches (among others).

I have corresponding Jenkins jobs that build when a commit is pushed to qa or dev.

If I create a new branch, i.e. feature/new (and merge dev into it), then push my feature/new branch to the repository, my existing Jenkins jobs for qa and dev (of this repository) are triggered for building.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I have no Jenkins job configured for the feature/new branch.

dev and qa of this repo are only supposed to build on pushes to dev or qa - "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" is selected in these jobs. It normally works just fine, I am wondering why these jobs trigger on a new (unrelated?) branch push?

Here's what I see on the Jenkins build info page:

```
Success Build #71 (Aug 25, 2022 12:09:38 PM)
add description
    No changes.
    

* Started by GitHub push by special-monkey
    Revision: 

    refs/remotes/origin/dev
    
* 

Started on Aug 25, 2022 12:09:29 PM
Started by event from 140.82.115.111 ⇒ https://jenkins/github-webhook/ on Thu Aug 25 12:09:29 EDT 2022
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 2b2902bfb82eb6f2bc55601c1151548e05c4feb4 (refs/remotes/origin/migration)
using credential Secret
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Secret
 > git ls-remote -h git@github.com:Org/xxx.git # timeout=10
Found 133 remote heads on git@github.com:Org/xxx.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/dev is: 7a53bbdd2e4ae7670f6c439131bedc93eb07efe4
Done. Took 0.36 sec
Changes found
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to verify the configurations of the Jenkins job to be sure if it's polling only for dev/qa branches or for all branches.